# Retrieving an embeded YouTube video from a wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

*tl;dr: I want to extract embeded Youtube video links from posts in a certain category*

I am currently developing a blog/article website. Consider the following: I have an index page that has a section for 2 featured videos. Let's say that I have a query and a loop that retrieves 2 latest posts from a category. Posts in this category always start with a featured video embeded using bootstrap:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
<!-- some text content follows -->
```

Currently I am using the following function to retrieve text excerpts from the post content:

```
function get_excerpt_by_id($post_id){
 $the_post = get_post($post_id); //Gets post ID
 $the_excerpt = $the_post->post_content; //Gets post_content to be used as a basis for the excerpt
 $excerpt_length = 30; //Sets excerpt length by word count
 $the_excerpt = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($the_excerpt)); //Strips tags and images
 $the_excerpt = html_entity_decode($the_excerpt, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
 $words = explode(' ', $the_excerpt, $excerpt_length + 1);

 if(count($words) > $excerpt_length) :
    array_pop($words);
    array_push($words, '…');
    $the_excerpt = implode(' ', $words);
 endif;
 return $the_excerpt;
}
```

The function takes the content from the post and extracts the first 30 words, while striping all the html tags and images.
How could I do the opposite? To somehow retrieve the embeded YouTube video and get rid of the rest? I have two ideas:

1. I could for example take the first X characters, find the end of the embed  and get rid of the rest.
2. I could add a special element into the post and take everying inside it. Something like:

   ```
   <span class="vid">...</span>
   ```
3. I could theoretically create posts only with the videos themselves and just use the_content(), but I wanted to avoid this solution as sites that just share videos with no added value to the user of the website get sometimes penalized by Google in search ranks.
4. I could directly extract the src element from the embed div.

Which would be the best approach or is there a better way to do this? If so, could you point me into the right direction?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the resources from the first answer as well as more research I made this function:

```
 <?php
        $args = array(
            'category_name'  => 'featured-video',
          'posts_per_page' => '2'
        );
        query_posts($args);      
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

        $content = $post->post_content;
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($content);
        $iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        foreach ($iframes as $frame) {
               echo '<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">        
                      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="'.$frame->getAttribute('src').'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div><br>';
        }

      endwhile; endif;    
        wp_reset_query();
      ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I could give you finished code, but try to do it yourself, you will probably need this in future.

You should use DOM and you could extract video ID with regex.
For example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuQLMXyGQOE
```

ID is `EuQLMXyGQOE`

http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Edit: If you are stuck, here is finished code
http://pastebin.com/FhV5yQTV

Comment: Thank you I will try to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.6.0 WordPress introduced a `get_media_embedded_in_content()` function to get embed content easily.

```
$media = get_media_embedded_in_content(
    apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ), 'video'
);

print_r($media);

// results
[
    0 => '<iframe>content</iframe>,
]
```

The supported audio types: 'audio', 'video', 'object', 'embed', or 'iframe'.

More information you can find here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_media_embedded_in_content/.